# Make jQuery animate smoother

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

How can I make jQuery animate smoother?
In Firefox it doesn't smooth like a chrome or even IE..

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to do?? Be specific maybe?

Comment: Im animating the left property of a div with a lot elements inside of it..

Comment: @Skizo You can use CSS transition to make it smoother.

Answer (score 0):

If you can achieve the animation with using css transitions instead, try them, and make a fallback to jquery animation using modernizr.

IE and chrome always seem to render jquery animations smoother.

Comment: Do you mean I should use css3 transitions and if this isn't a modern browser, it will use the jquery animate?

Comment: Thats right, after installing modernizr you can use if(Modernizr.csstransitions) to test if a browser supports css3 transitions.

Comment: css3 transitions can animate the left property of an element?